# Custom pickling of tuple-derived class on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I have a class `Record`, which references a database record by its primary key, ID, and keeps some cached information.

```
    class Record:
        def __init__( self, id ):
            self.id = id
            self.various_cached_info = spam
```

I also have a class `RecordCollection`, which is a tuple of `Records`.

```
    from typing import Tuple, TypeVar

    TRecord = TypeVar( "TRecord", bound = Record )

    class RecordCollection( Tuple[TRecord, ...] ):
        pass
```

Now, **when I pickle a `RecordCollection`, how can I change this class to only pickle the IDs** (as a list of `ints`)?

I have tried:

- changing `Record.__getstate__` to just include the ID, and discard the cached information. This helps, but `RecordCollection` still pickles the *type-name* "`Record`" for every single item in the array.
- changing `RecordCollection.__getstate__` to include only a list of IDs, but something behind the hood is pickling the `tuple` part elsewhere.

```
    import json
    import jsonpickle

    a = Record( 1 )
    b = Record( 2 )
    c = Record( 3 )

    l = RecordCollection( (a, b, c) )

    print( json.dumps( json.loads( jsonpickle.dumps( l ) ), indent = 4 ) )
```

Comment: You could use a tuple comprehension for a tuple of ints `tuple(i.id for i in l)` or a list comprehension for a list of ints `[i.id for i in l]`. Neither of these would require you to change your class in any way.

Comment: If you really want to add it to your class you could create a method named something like  `ids(self)` and have it return the ids. So your class would look like `class RecordCollection( Tuple[TRecord, ...] ): ;    def ids(self): ;        return tuple(i.id for i in self)` and the just call it like `l.ids()`.